# Best way to draw a line without using a canvas C#

Tags: c#, wpf, line

I am wondering what the best way to draw a line, on a maximum value, from a list is without using a canvas?

I have identified the Max, Min and Median I'm wondering what the best way to draw a line/point without using a canvas would be?

```
public partial class SpectrumControl : UserControl
{
    private double Highest;
    private double Minimum;
    private double Median;
    private int Total;
    private int CellWidth;

    public int Width { get; set; }

    public SpectrumControl()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Bind(KLayer klayer)
    {
        if (Width == 0)
        {
            Width = 300;
        }

        Highest = klayer.Values.Max();
        Minimum = klayer.Values.Min();
        Median = ((Highest - Minimum) / 2) + Minimum;
        Total = klayer.Values.Count;
        CellWidth = Width / Total;
        int rowNumber = 0;
        foreach (var item in klayer.Values)
        {
            var label = CreateLabel(item, rowNumber);
            Color backgroundColour = GetColour(item);
            stk1.Children.Add(label);
            rowNumber++;
        }
    }

    private Label CreateLabel(double item, int rowNumber)
    {

        var label = new Label()
        {
            Background = new SolidColorBrush(GetColour(item)),
            Width = CellWidth
        };
        return label;

    }

    private Color GetColour(double item)
    {
        byte a = Convert.ToByte(GetTransparency(item)*255);
        Color backgroundColour;
        if (item < Median)
        {
            backgroundColour = Color.FromArgb(a, 128, 128, 255);
        }
        else if (item > Median)
        {
            backgroundColour = Color.FromArgb(a, 255, 128, 128);
        }
        else
        {
            backgroundColour = Colors.White;
        }

        return backgroundColour;
    }

    private double GetTransparency(double item)
    {
        double x = Highest - Minimum;
        double difference;
        if (item > Median)
        {
            difference = item - Median;
        }
        else
        {
            difference = Median - item;
        }

        var fraction = difference / x;
        return fraction;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use a canvas?

Comment: Just been told to avoid using a canvas for the time being, I done research and everyone is using a canvas, is it possible at all or would I be better using a canvas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, assuming you are going to use something like `GridPanel` or any other panel, really, you could do this:

```
var line = new Line();
line.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightSteelBlue;
line.X1 = 1;
line.X2 = 50;
line.Y1 = 1;
line.Y2 = 50;
line.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
line.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
line.StrokeThickness = 2;
grid.Children.Add(line);
```

Same thing may be achieved in XAML, but it looks like you prefer to work in code-behind, so that is what I posted here.

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.line%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

I'm not sure why you'd avoid canvas, though (well, why someone told you to do that).  I've created plenty of plots using canvas.

Comment: thanks that was exactly what I was needing. I'm not 100% myself why they have told me to not do it in XAML